# Font color for UILabel not changing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, uistoryboard, uifont

I am trying to display numbers on a UILabel with a bold black font and size 50.

After some failed attempts I just realized that no matter what color I set the font to, it always gets set to lightGray. Is there something else I need to do other than the below?

```
[DisplayLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:"HelveticaNeue-Bold"] size:50]];
DisplayLabel.textColor = [UIColor brownColor];
DisplayLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

I am adding the label using the storyboard to a view.

Comment: Does the alignment and font change though when you do it programmatically?

Comment: The font size and alignment definitely change programmatically. Its just the color that does not change.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Make sure your label's behavior like that.  [image]

Comment: Where do I find this? I cannot find it.

Comment: Found it. I just enabled the label programmatically. Worked!

Comment: @user220201 how did you activate it programmatically?

Answer (score 61):

I encountered the same issue but it was cause by setting a custom color in the storyboard.  Apparently you must have the color attribute set to `default` in order to change it programatically.  I found this true with all `UIView`s.

Comment: Thank you, what an odd issue... I don't think I'd ever have figured this out on my own!

Comment: No problem.  Glad to save anyone the headache that I went through.

Comment: i suppouse thats some kind of bug, not a feature

Comment: Wow. I wasted so much time trying to get a label in a xib that we use over and over to change and it wouldn't.  Thanks.

Swift 4, Xcode Version 10.1 (10B61)

Comment: Running into the same bug. I believe it doesn't affect Attributed Text Labels

Answer (score 2):

I was trying change programtelly the textcolor of a UILabel in a UITabelViewCell in cellForRowAt. And the label just change the textcolor after being reloaded.

I could change the label textColor in the beggining after change the TEXTCOLOR IN STORYBOARD TO DEFAULT and i change it programatelly.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that bug is pretty annoying. Just relaunch the Xcode and it will work good

Answer (score -1):

I got this to work for a table or collection view cell by setting the color first to a system color, then to my custom color in cellForRowAtIndexPath e.g.

```
myLabel.textColor = .black
myLabel.textColor = UIColor(named: "My custom color")
```