# UILabel text color is not changing programmatically, if I set the text color in nib and define that color in assets

Tags: ios, iphone, swift4.1, xcode9.4

The issues is cause by setting a custom color in the storyboard,its not related to custom font.

**Step 1:** Define color in Assets Folder

[image]

**Step 2:** Set that color as label text color

[image]

**Step 3:** Change the text color in code

[image]

**Label background color is changing but text color is not changing**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Font color for UILabel not changing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25355709/font-color-for-uilabel-not-changing)

Comment: What result do you get? And What color are you expecting to get as a result of your code? You're setting the label to have different colors (the one set in storyboard vs the one set on code)

Comment: I had the same issue. This answer worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51559466/9769851

Answer (score 8):

I faced the exact same problem. I suppose it's a bug in the xCode. The issue arrises when you set custom colour in storyboard or xib. What you can do:

1. Use some standard colour in your nib file/storyboard
2. If you want to change it with some colour asset this can be done programmatically at any time

I tried it and it works.