# iOS custom view，change UILabel textColor/isHidden not working

Tags: ios, swift

Swift 4.2/iOS 12/Xcode 10.
I made a custom view with a UILabel in it(name StepView.xib & StepView.swift)，UILabel in xib file connect to swift file via IBOutlet.Then, I use StepView in viewController. When I want to change UILabel textColor in viewController, It doesn't work, I want to know the reason.

```
class StepView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var labels: [UILabel]!

    ...

    private func setSelected(current phase: ClosedRange<Int>,
                             select srange: ClosedRange<Int>){
        for p in phase {
            labels[p].textColor = R.color.mainTextColor()
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Init
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
       super.init(coder: aDecoder)
       initSubviews()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        initSubviews()
    }

    func initSubviews() {

       let nib = UINib(nibName: "StepView", bundle: Bundle(for: type(of: self)))
       nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)
       contentView.frame = bounds
       addSubview(contentView)
    }
}
```

More info:
I have set the UILabel's Color in XIB，then I change UILabel's Color in Code, It's invalid. I reset the UILabel Color to Default, then I change UILabel's Color in Code, It's work. I want to know the reason.

Comment: Where is the code you are invoking to change `textColor` from `UIViewController`

Comment: I just invoking setSelected(current: 1...3,select: 4...5) in viewDidLoad of viewController.

Comment: In your setSelect method you are changing the color of selected ones but not reseting the unselected labels colors.

Comment: The same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25355709/font-color-for-uilabel-not-changing/51559466#51559466

Answer (score 0):

Set and Reset textColors of selected Labels and unSelected Labels.

```
 private func setSelected(current phase: ClosedRange<Int>,
                             select srange: ClosedRange<Int>){
        for p in phase {
            labels[p].textColor = R.color.mainTextColor()
        }
        for s in srange {
            labels[s].textColor = R.color.unSelectedColor()
        }
    }
```